# How to assign Owner to cloned TMenuItem?

Tags: delphi, menuitem, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

When I create a `TmenuItem` programmatically the usual way, the `Owner` of the created menu item is passed as a parameter in the `Create` function, e.g.:

```
var NewMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(MainMen1);
```

However, when creating a menu item by CLONING it, assigning its Owner property causes an error:

```
function CloneMenuItem(SourceItem: TMenuItem): TMenuItem;
begin
  with SourceItem do  
    Result := Vcl.Menus.NewItem(Caption, Shortcut, Checked, Enabled, OnClick, HelpContext, Name + 'Cloned'); 
  //Result.Owner := pmMyPopupMenu; // ERROR
end;
```

So how can I specify the Owner of a cloned `TMenuItem`?

Comment: You can clone a `TMenuItem` by means of `TMenuItem.Create`. Just create it with your desired owner and then set its `Caption`, `Shortcut`, `Checked`, etc. properties.

Comment: `Vcl.Menus.NewItem` parameters for `Hint` and `Break` properties are MISSING. Did Embarcadero forget to include these properties in `Vcl.Menus.NewItem` parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the owner using [TComponent.InsertComponent](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TComponent.InsertComponent) method like:.

```
function CloneMenuItem(SourceItem: TMenuItem): TMenuItem;
begin
  with SourceItem do  
    Result := Vcl.Menus.NewItem(Caption, Shortcut, Checked, Enabled, OnClick, HelpContext, Name + 'Cloned'); 
  pmMyPopupMenu.InsertComponent(Result);
  pmMyPopupMenu.Items.Add(Result);
end;
```

If you look at `NewItem` function implementation in `Vcl.Menus`, it simply creates an item with `nil` as owner and sets the passed properties. Nothing smart there. I'd prefer inline code in your case or a local function that explicitly sets the owner on item creation.

Comment: Thanks. IMO, there are several potentially misleading function names in the Delphi universe.